# How to read nested JSON using AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

I am trying to read an nested JSON using AngularJS. Following is the nested JSON :

```
{
  "results": [
    {
      "id": "D1",
      "name": "A",
    },
    {
      "id": "D2",
      "name": "B",
    }
  ]
}
```

Following is the AngularJS controller which fetches the JSON data from PHP in the form [object object]
When I try to read the JSON it gives an undefined value.

```
function MyController($scope, $http) {
    $http({
        method: 'GET',
        data: "action=0",
        url: 'a.php'
    }).then(function(data) {
        alert("Hello" +data);    //alerts Hello[object Object]
        $scope.legs = data.results;
        alert($scope.legs);     //alerts undefined
    });

}
```

The html code which is trying to print the JSON is :

```
<tr ng-repeat="l in legs">
  <td>{{ l.id }}</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: try ``alert("Hello", data);`` so you don't get a stringified version of an object

Comment: where is `output` defined? wouldn't you want `data.results` in your http callback?

Comment: What is output here?

Comment: Corrected the variable

Answer (score 0):

You can check how $http works in https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http

You do not get the response body directly as result of the promise, you'll get an object with more info about the HTTP request, to get the body or data you should access its `data` property:

```
function MyController($scope, $http) {
    $http({
        method: 'GET',
        data: "action=0",
        url: 'a.php'
    }).then(function(response) {
        $scope.legs = response.data.results;
    });

}
```

I'm assuming your server is correctly setting response headers for JSON in order to activate the response transforms.

Comment: If you don't want to handle response.data you can use **.success** instead of **.then**. Which will give you the _data_ directly.

Comment: @Tobi ***The `$http` legacy promise methods `success` and `error` have been deprecated. Use the standard `then` method instead.*** https://code.angularjs.org/1.5.8/docs/api/ng/service/$http#deprecation-notice

Comment: When I alert `response`, it alerts `[object Object]`.
But when I alert `$scope.legs` as mentioned in the above solution, it alerts `undefined`
And PHP code is setting up the returned JSON header as `header('Content-Type: application/json');`

Answer (score 0):

Please read up on $http promises here: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http

You will see that the successCallback has a parameter that is the response rather than the data itself. The response is an object that contains the **data**. You will need to extract your JSON data from this object  ***data*** .

Modify this code:

```
}).then(function(data) {
    alert("Hello" +data);    //alerts Hello[object Object]
    $scope.legs = data.results;
    alert($scope.legs);     //alerts undefined
});
```

to :

```
}).then(function(response) {
    alert("Hello" + response.data);   
    $scope.legs = response.data.results;
    alert($scope.legs);
});
```

Your $scope.legs will now have the JSON data. ng-repeat should work just fine.